# Listview still clickable even though is replaced by clicked fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

i have the following problem:
i'm developing an app using : 
`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener`

This is using a `ViewPager`. So the initial main_activity.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the framgent_container.xml contains the following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/items_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adv_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_adv" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adv_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So here is the problem: 
I get the list displayed correctly and the adv_image on top of it. When i click on one item of my list i can see the item as it should be displayed. (Is a linear layout with an image view and a description underneath within a scroll view). 
**BUT** 
When i click the image view (which is not clickable)! 
another item of the previous list is displayed. Which makes me assume that the Listview is still there (behind my article? weird). And even if i click a little bit above the article image it triggers the adv_image url, which exists only on the listview and not inside this fragment..

The code to replace the list view with the article fragment is the following.

```
public class ArticlesListFragment extends ListFragment {
```

which onCreateView inflates the following

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_list, container, false);
```

which has the following function

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment = new Article();

    args.putString("unique_id", ((ArticleItem) v.getTag()).ID);

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack("HomePage");
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    ft.commit();

}
```

so any ideas????? i have tried to replace several different stuff onitemclick..but i still haven't got any luck..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you adding a `Fragment` on top of another `Fragment`? An `ImageView` on top of a `Fragment`? or an `ImageView` on top of a `ListView`?

Comment: I have a FragmentList which contains an imageView on top of a ListView, and oncliked item a Fragment replaces the fragment list. This new fragment contains an ImageView and below a TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements which appear later in the XML will have be placed higher, so in the XML you've shown above, the ListView will appear above the ImageView.  If you want the ImageView to be on top then swap their order.

Unrelated notes:

1) `fill_parent` is identical to `match_parent` (but `match_parent` is preferred)

2) You only need to prefix an id with `+` on the first occasion it is encountered in the AXML (you've done it twice for `adv_image`).

Comment: It makes sense..i didn't know it..I'll check right now :)

Comment: Well i have tried to make that work, by setting the Fragment views in Relative layout and adding layout_above the previous elements, but it didnt do the trick. I managed to fix this issue by setting all the new fragment into a Scrollview..which it seems that it is always on top of other elements. :-/ Thanks also about the unrelated notes, changes applied :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :) so maybe it's possible that touches pass through an uppermost image view, but that ScrollViews capture everything.